# set new Image on ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I created an XML layout for my project with an `ImageView` in it. I add a default image for `imageView`. Now programatically I am getting that `imageview` and trying to change the image source using `imgView.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);`.

**The problem is that both images are showing** - the default image displays behind programatically added one.

I tried:

- `imgView.setImageResource(0);`
- `imgView.setImageDrawable(null);`
- `imgView.setAlpha(0);`
- `imgView.setImageBitmap(null);`

  ...but the default image is still visible.

Comment: please provide your xml r u using src or background for image provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting the background of the `ImageView` in the xml file, then it will remain until you clear the background.  `ImageView` is odd in that it can display two images, background and source.  Use the attribute `android:src` to set the source image and 'android:background' to set the background.  All the methods you described will replace the source image but keep the background unchanged.

Comment: thanks,I set default image as img resource and then in code I am setting new image bitmap its replacing previous one.thanks